# Jquery: show message on disabled button click/hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display info message if user click disabled button. My code makes it but info message appears only for short moment and then previous success message continues displaying. How to change code to force info message halt and don't disappear?

> UPDATED: I made tiny changes in my code and now it disables button
>   just after first click and displays success message(earlier to disable I should click once again)but I'd want if user occasionally press disabled button again he will receive info message. How to make it possible?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s1-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    $.post(
      "/run-key-gen-process/",
      onAjaxSuccess
    );

    function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
      if (data == "Key was succesfully generated an tested!") {
        $("#jmessage").addClass("alert alert-success")
          .text(data).fadeOut(6000);
      }
      $('#s1-btn').click(function() {
        $("#jmessage").removeClass("alert alert-success").addClass("alert alert-info")
          .text("Button is disabled since you already generated and tested the key");
      });
    };
  });
})
```

template.html

```
<div class="row" id="div-st1">
  <div class="col-md-3 ">
    <button type="submit" method="POST" id="s1-btn" class="form-inline btn btn-info pull-left">Generate</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 " id="jmessage" role="alert"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try change `button type from submit to button`

Comment: In your code, is your button getting disabled at first click?

Comment: First click  runs key generation and after it and successful message coming submit button should be disabled and inform user about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified my code like this and now it does what it should. If user clicks button it runs key generation, success message displays and button became disabled. If user clicks/moves mouse on disabled button info message appears.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s1-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $("#div-st1").mouseenter(function() {
      $("#jmessage").removeClass("alert alert-success").addClass("alert alert-info")
        .text("Button is disabled since you already generated and tested the key");
    });
    $.post(
      "/run-key-gen-process/",
      onAjaxSuccess
    );

    function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
      if (data == "Key was succesfully generated an tested!") {
        $("#jmessage").addClass("alert alert-success")
          .text(data);
      }
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is the rebinding of the `click` event on the same button again in the success callback, you can change to this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#s1-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var isDisabled = $this.is('disabled');
        if (isDisabled) {
          $("#jmessage").removeClass("alert alert-success").addClass("alert alert-info")
            .text("Button is disabled since you already generated and tested the key");
          return !isDisabled;
        } else {
          $this.prop('disabled', !isDisabled); // <-----disable it here.
          $.post(
            "/run-key-gen-process/",
            onAjaxSuccess
          );
        }

        function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
          if (data == "Key was succesfully generated an tested!") {
            $this.prop('disabled', !!data);// <-----enable it here.
            $("#jmessage").removeClass("alert alert-info").addClass("alert alert-success")
              .text(data).fadeOut(6000);
          }
        };
      });
    })
```

Comment: When I copy/paste your code unfortunately nothing changed: info message  still appears on short moment and then success message continues to display. Although message banner changed green color to blue (like it was early in my code too.)

Comment: And I suggest  ajax request should be early in code since button must be disabled after ajax will successful.

Comment: The code you provided disables button immediately after click and don't show info message. Instead while button already disabled continue showing success message. But I need first run code to generate key and only after it if user will want to press the button once again it should display to him info message.Something like this.